# Simple question regarding doing action on checkbox click in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I must have looked at 10-15 tutorials on this already but just cannot get this to work, so in my .js I have:

```
    jQuery('#sports : checkbox').click(function() {

alert('it works');

});
```

and in my .html doc I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sports"  />
```

It just won't work, no matter what I try and I have tried every variation I can come up with, the input checkbox isn't in a DIV or anything (but I am also curious how to reference it if it is in a div.. just for a control on this test, I have tried this and it works fine (where "testdiv" is a name of a DIV in my document:

```
   jQuery('#testdiv').click(function() {

alert('it works');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without spaces:

```
jQuery('#sports:checkbox')
```

and you have to give the input element the correct ID (`#` selects elements with the corresponding ID):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sports"  id="sports" />
```

Or you search for attribute `name`:

```
jQuery('input:checkbox[name=sports]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is off a bit, you need this instead (for your current markup):

```
jQuery(':checkbox[name=sports]').click(function() {
  alert('it works');
});
```

When you do a `#sports : checkbox` selector it's looking for...well I'm not sure what, but `#sports :checkbox` is looking for a `<input type="checkbox" />` *inside* an element with `id="sports"`.  The `[name=sports]` is using the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).  You can find a full list of selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an id to your html? The # in jQuery refers you are selecting an id.